# Retrieving PHP Cookie

Tags: php, html

I am trying to use a cookie in stored using PHP to determine if a user is logged in.

I am setting the cookie using the following:

```
else $keep_alive = time()+(86400 * 14);
setcookie("id",mysql_result($result, 0, "id"),$keep_alive, "/", "mydomain.com");
```

When I attempt to get the value of 'id' I am able to retrieve it using the following, so long as I do so before the headers are sent.

```
$id = $_COOKIE['id'];
```

However, if the page headers have already been sent the value of 'id' isn't retrieved. Is it not possible to get the value of a cookie after the headers are sent, or am I missing something?

Comment: Wait, are you saying you can't READ (not set, then read) the cookie after the headers are sent?

Comment: I am unable to READ after the headers are sent. The cookie is already set (visible when viewing cookies in my browser(s)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I was trying to get the cookie values in my include file, which only works with a relative path. So http://www.example.com/directory/page.php would have to be referenced as ./directory/page.php in my include statement for the cookie to be retrievable. I'm not sure if this a bug with PHP or if they intend to make it work that way, but all is well now.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are set/sent by headers.  You can't send headers twice, so if you've already sent the headers you can't set a cookie on this page load.  Make sure you don't print anything out before sending the cookie, or buffer it (`ob_start`, etc.)

Comment: Does that effect retrieving cookie values? I am not trying to set after the headers have been sent, just receive their values.

Comment: Is the value something truthy?

Comment: It's the user's id number that is stored within my database. In my testing, the value of $_COOKIE['id'] should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

[ob_start() and ob_end_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

This way headers aren't sent until the end function is called.